Binwalk Windows 11
I'm trying to install Binwalk on Windows. Everything seems to be installed, but when I try to start python3 setup.py installin response I get :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\clust\binwalk-master\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Command
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\clust\binwalk-master\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    from distutils.core import setup, Command
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
I tried to reinstall absolutely everything, from binwalk-master to Python itself and libraries...

By libraries you mean the python packages? So you have already tried to do pip install setuptools distutils?

Try this fork
